# collectionViewCells interact

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view and each cell has a button,
I added an IB-action that is called when the button is pressed.

My issue is that when a certain button is tapped I want to change not only the background color of that button, I want to change all buttons in all the cells

I'm not sure how to implement this...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Somthg like this

Take a `var selectedIndex : Int = -1`

in `cellForItemAt`

```
 cell.button.tag = indexpath.item
if selectedIndex == indexPath.item{
   cell.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue // New Color
}
else{
   cell.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray // Deafult color
}
```

in `Button Action`

```
selectedIndex = sender.tag
collectionView.ReloadData()
```

Comment: The question points out that all should get a red background, not only the one selected.

Comment: @Oxthor OHH I MISS READ IT, LET ME CHANGE MY ANSWER.

Comment: Actually I want the button tapped to get black background color and the rest to have a blue background

Answer (score 0):

When you pressed to the button you should notify your collectionView class holder (by `delegate` pattern or using a `closure`) that right now all buttons should be changed. Then you should force change all visible buttons (take all `visibleCells` of collectionView and change the buttons style) and also in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method change the button style for every other buttons which is invisible right now.